# Setting multiple alarms, overriding eachother

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to multiple different time alarms in my app.
My app is getting from user some data and store it in SQLite DB.
When i'm putting new data to DB i'm sending intent and setting alarm like these

```
class MainActivity ...
public id=0;
private void addNewItem() {

    String itemName = etItem.getText().toString();

    String itemReturndate = dpReturndate.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + (dpReturndate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dpReturndate.getYear();


        updateListViewData();
        AlarmHelper alarm = new AlarmHelper();
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.NOTIFY");
        intent.putExtra("time", itemReturndate);
        intent.putExtra("name", itemName);
        intent.putExtra("id",id);
        id++;
        alarm.SetAlarm(getApplicationContext(), intent);        
    }
```

And here i handle it by this class

```
public class AlarmHelper extends BroadcastReceiver
{

int j = 0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();
    NotificationManager mNM;
    Log.d("Time from notific", intent.getExtras().getString("time"));
    Log.d("name from notific", intent.getExtras().getString("name"));

    mNM = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Zwrot przedmiotu",System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, intent.getExtras().getInt("id"), new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, context.getText(R.string.alarm_service_label),  intent.getExtras().getString("name") + j  , contentIntent);
    mNM.notify(R.string.alarm_service_label, notification);
    notification.flags|= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    j++;

    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, intent.getExtras().getInt("id"), intent, 0);
    Log.d("show me time", intent.getExtras().getString("time"));
    intent.putExtra("intentNumber",j);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+22000, pi);
}
```

So when i add 2 or more things to DB, i get alarm with name from 1st object that i add and time from the last one.

The alarm now i set for 22sec from current time for tests, but its gonna be changed for "time" that i recive from intent

What am i doing wrong? Why alarm is overriding time and not creating 3 different alarms?

thanks for help

update, after change i get both notifications at the same time (the 2nd is covering 1st, but on logs both launched at the same time).
The time is still overrided by the last one.

Comment: as far as I can see, Your pending intent will get always the same request code. J++ will always give 1.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs yes, You are right, i fixxed it, but still there is issue with overriding time activation

Comment: what You mean with overriding? If I understand this the right way, the alarms happens at the same time? This is maybe because You set only one time in Your alarm manager: System.currentTimeMillis()+22000...<--this will always be the same time